# How many addresses are sent in response to a getaddr message?

Tags: protocol, bitcoin-core, network

I've been trying to determine the number of addresses a node sends when it receives a getaddr message but I'm a little confused.

On one hand, on addrman.h/.cpp I can see that:

```
// the maximum percentage of nodes to return in a getaddr call
#define ADDRMAN_GETADDR_MAX_PCT 23

// the maximum number of nodes to return in a getaddr call
#define ADDRMAN_GETADDR_MAX 2500
```

[...]

```
int nNodes = ADDRMAN_GETADDR_MAX_PCT*vRandom.size()/100;
if (nNodes > ADDRMAN_GETADDR_MAX)
    nNodes = ADDRMAN_GETADDR_MAX;
```

So it seems that the number of addresses sent is the smaller of the two conditions, namely, 23% of the (active known) nodes or 2500 nodes.

But on the other hand, from the [bitcoin wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Satoshi_Client_Node_Discovery):

> The getaddr message sends a request to a node asking for information about known active peers to help with identifying potential nodes in the network. **The response to receiving this message is to transmit an addr message** with one or more peers from a database of known active peers.

...and...

> [About addr messages] **If the sender sent over 1000 addresses, they are all ignored.**

So, why does a node try to send 2500 addresses if the receiver is going to discard them? Why not sending at most 1000 addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result from `CAddrMan::GetAddr()` is fed to `CNode::PushAddress`, which filters out addresses the peer already has, and inserts them in a temporary buffer of up to 1000 addresses.

Later, in `SendMessages()`, the contents of that buffer is sent out periodically.

Answer (score 0):

According to the wiki, it seems like these are **"Ongoing "addr" advertisements"** thus unsolicited.